# Execution failed for task ':compileArmv7DebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic

Tratando de compilar un proyecto el cual copie desde mi repositorio presenta el siguiente problema:

```
C:\Users\PterPmntaM\AplicacionesIonic\unicesarApp\platforms\android\src\org\crosswalk\engine\XWalkWebViewEngine.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
import org.xwalk.core.XWalkGetBitmapCallback;
                     ^
  symbol:   class XWalkGetBitmapCallback
  location: package org.xwalk.core

C:\Users\PterPmntaM\AplicacionesIonic\unicesarApp\platforms\android\src\org\crosswalk\engine\XWalkCordovaClientCertRequest.java:55: error: cannot find symbol

        return request.getKeyTypes();
                      ^
  symbol:   method getKeyTypes()
  location: variable request of type ClientCertRequest
C:\Users\PterPmntaM\AplicacionesIonic\unicesarApp\platforms\android\src\org\crosswalk\engine\XWalkCordovaClientCertRequest.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
        return request.getPrincipals();
                      ^
  symbol:   method getPrincipals()
  location: variable request of type ClientCertRequest

C:\Users\PterPmntaM\AplicacionesIonic\unicesarApp\platforms\android\src\org\crosswalk\engine\XWalkWebViewEngine.java:114: error: cannot find symbol

                                            new XWalkGetBitmapCallback() {
                                                ^
  symbol: class XWalkGetBitmapCallback

C:\Users\PterPmntaM\AplicacionesIonic\unicesarApp\platforms\android\src\org\crosswalk\engine\XWalkWebViewEngine.java:238: error: cannot find symbol

            webView.getExtensionManager().loadExtension(XWALK_EXTENSIONS_FOLDER + File.separator + path);
                   ^
  symbol:   method getExtensionManager()
  location: variable webView of type XWalkCordovaView

C:\Users\PterPmntaM\AplicacionesIonic\unicesarApp\platforms\android\src\org\crosswalk\engine\XWalkCordovaView.java:93: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

    @Override
    ^

Note: C:\Users\PterPmntaM\AplicacionesIonic\unicesarApp\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\splashscreen\SplashScreen.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
6 errors

:compileArmv7DebugJavaWithJavac FAILED




BUILD FAILED

Total time: 29.27 secs

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileArmv7DebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
C:\Users\PterPmntaM\AplicacionesIonic\unicesarApp\platforms\android\src\org\crosswalk\engine\XWalkWebViewEngine.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
import org.xwalk.core.XWalkGetBitmapCallback;
                     ^
  symbol:   class XWalkGetBitmapCallback
  location: package org.xwalk.core
C:\Users\PterPmntaM\AplicacionesIonic\unicesarApp\platforms\android\src\org\crosswalk\engine\XWalkCordovaClientCertRequest.java:55: error: cannot find symbol
        return request.getKeyTypes();
                      ^
  symbol:   method getKeyTypes()
  location: variable request of type ClientCertRequest
C:\Users\PterPmntaM\AplicacionesIonic\unicesarApp\platforms\android\src\org\crosswalk\engine\XWalkCordovaClientCertRequest.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
        return request.getPrincipals();
                      ^
  symbol:   method getPrincipals()
  location: variable request of type ClientCertRequest
C:\Users\PterPmntaM\AplicacionesIonic\unicesarApp\platforms\android\src\org\crosswalk\engine\XWalkWebViewEngine.java:114: error: cannot find symbol
                                            new XWalkGetBitmapCallback() {
                                                ^
  symbol: class XWalkGetBitmapCallback
C:\Users\PterPmntaM\AplicacionesIonic\unicesarApp\platforms\android\src\org\crosswalk\engine\XWalkWebViewEngine.java:238: error: cannot find symbol
            webView.getExtensionManager().loadExtension(XWALK_EXTENSIONS_FOLDER + File.separator + path);
                   ^
  symbol:   method getExtensionManager()
  location: variable webView of type XWalkCordovaView
C:\Users\PterPmntaM\AplicacionesIonic\unicesarApp\platforms\android\src\org\crosswalk\engine\XWalkCordovaView.java:93: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
Note: C:\Users\PterPmntaM\AplicacionesIonic\unicesarApp\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\splashscreen\SplashScreen.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
6 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileArmv7DebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
```

Ejecuto el codigo

`ionic build android`

y aparece ese error, he probado unas soluciones que anteriormente habia probado, pero sigue todo igual, el mismo error.